# In windows from the cmd prompt you type Win and it got you back to the GUI, what's the equivalent in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Good evening, i am used to windows, but would like to know how to get from Ubuntu command line to launching Ubuntu GUI. What command would i use. In windows, WIN did the trick, what is it in Ubuntu ver16-18

Comment: If you started a terminal from the gui (typically ctrl-alt-t), then typing exit will exit the terminal and return you to the gui.

Comment: What do you mean ? Did you downloaded the Ubuntu server ? `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will do the work if you want to download gui

Comment: If, for some reason, the GUI on your Ubuntu desktop doesn't start, you would type `startx` to start it, or at least get an error message that tells you why it didn't start in the first place. But I doubt whether that is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it used to work like that in Windows 3.1. Then, the system would boot to an MS-DOS prompt, and `win` would load Windows 3.

Linux in the early days also used to boot to the console, the `TTY`, giving most commonly a Bash prompt. Then, typing `startx` would load the graphical display server Xorg.

That answers your question, but in principle you do not need that anymore, neither in Windows nor in popular Linux distributions. These are set up to immediately launch a desktop environment (or at least a window manager). Instead, to go to the terminal, you launch a **terminal emulator**. That is a graphical application that emulates a console where you type commands. You exit that emulator by typing `exit` at the prompt, or by closing the emulator in another way (clicking the close button on the title bar, selecting "Quit" from the menu, etc.)

In Linux, and this is as opposed to Windows, you still can move to a console, away from your graphical environment. Press the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and you will be moved out of your graphical environment to a pure text console, TTY3, where you will see a prompt to log in. Text consoles are also available on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> etc. You can log in on all of these and do different things if you wish.

To return to your graphical environment, which runs on TTY2, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. The login display manager lives on TTY1. A few years ago, the graphical environment was on TTY7.

Answer (score 0):

To stop GUI session completely and switch to CLI one can use

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

To get back from CLI to GUI one can use

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```